# Xilinx simulator bug or design error?

Tags: vhdl, xilinx, vivado

I have the following code in VHDL:

```
process(RESET_N, CLK)
begin
    if RESET_N = '0' then
        COUNTER <= X"0";
    else  
        if rising_edge(CLK) then
          if EN = '0' then
             COUNTER <= std_logic_vector(to_unsigned(to_integer(unsigned(COUNTER)) + 1, 4));
          end if;
       end if;
    end if;
end process;
```

There is a transition which isn't supposed take place. Am I wrong?

[image]

Please help me Xilinx certainly can't ! The simulator is Vivado 2016.2.

Comment: Look into how the clock is started and stopped : suspect a single delta cycle glitch. We can't tell any more from the posted fragment, it isn't an MCVE. http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: `COUNTER <= std_logic_vector(to_unsigned(to_integer(unsigned(COUNTER)) + 1, 4));` If you made `COUNTER` of type `unsigned` in the first place, this line would be as simple as `COUNTER <= COUNTER + 1;`.

Comment: Thank you for your comments.

The COUNTER INCREMENT is the only way Vivado will accept it. It is std_logic_vector and you have to make these conversions to increment that signal.

The Clock is running all the time, but it is mapped to the CLK signal shown in the screenshot with an Enable signal. When that Enable signal is active the CLK is mapped to the active clock. Otherwise the CLK is staying low. That is the behavior the FPGA will face in realty later on.

Comment: Without seeing the time scale and determining the time on the left hand edge of the waveform and lacking an MCVE we can't tell you're not seeing a pipeline delay somewhere. However your process does the [right thing](http://i.stack.imgur.com/2NJJH.png) with a simple MCVE.

Comment: From you comment it sounds like a delta delay glitch on your enabled clock, noting EN is always low (true). You should be gating a rising edge clock so when it is disabled it is high.

Comment: You did not understand my comment. You only need the conversions because you made a counter of type `std_logic_vector`. Use the `ieee.numeric_std.all` library, give the counter type `unsigned` instead, and you do not need the conversions.

Answer (score 0):

OK this is what I found out. It was in fact my testbenchs fault.

Noone at Xilinx was able to point that out. The Testbench that I have not submitted here was faulty.

The way I designed it (thought that would be fine) that with the EN signal going low the CLK_EN signal is triggered. That CLK_EN signal is then allowing to map the MAIN_CLK to the CLK that you can see in the screenshot.

So rather doing it like this

```
CLK_process :process
begin     
    CLK <= '0'; wait for CLK_period/2;
    CLK <= '1'; wait for CLK_period/2;
end process;

FTDI_CLK    <= CLK when CLK_EN = '1' else 'Z';
```

You should do it like this:

```
MAIN_CLK_process :process
begin
    MAIN_CLK<= not MAIN_CLK; wait for CLK_period/2;
end process;

CLK_process :process
begin
    wait for CLK_period/2;
    if CLK_EN = '1' then
        CLK <= not CLK;
    else
        CLK <= '0';
    end if; 
end process;
```

I understand that the information I provided was incomplete. Apologies for that.